# How to write a Django model field that refers to another field in the same model?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called booking with two foreignkeys: artists and venues.
Artist can request to book venues but venues can also request to book artists. I want to save in the model who tries to book who.
How would I go about doing this?

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    #relationships
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    requester = # Either artist or venue (preferablly pointing to the object) How do I write this?
```

I thought about creating another foreignkey, but that would have to be conditional as it could be either artist or venue. And that would lead to duplication in the database.

I also thought about creating a simple boolean "booked_by_artist", but that would not point to *which* artist.

Comment: Usually one would use a "polymorphic"/generic relationship for a case like this. Django enables it with their [Content types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: Generic relation does not solve the problem here, as it is used to prevent code duplication for a foreign key of **non-interconnected** models.
Through Generic Relation we can create, a generic model `Bookings` for both `Artist` and `Venue`, but each `Bookings` object created will be different for them. Moreover, the `Bookings` object created by any one will not be able to provide `ForeignKey` for the other.

***The most straight forward way*** to achieve this is through creating objects by providing only one among the `artist` and `venue` ForeignKey. And then updating the other after first save. You can achieve this by requiring null and blank to be true on both of foreign fields, and then later mitigate that in clean method. Mind you, clean method must be manually called in overridden `save` method otherwise, it does not get called by default. Here is the `Bookings` model:

```
class Bookings(models.Model):
    requester = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="artist_booking")
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="venue_booking")

    def clean(self):
        if self.artist and self.venue:
        raise ValidationError('A booking cannot have both an artist and a venue.')
        super(Bookings,self).clean()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.clean() 
        if not self.requester:
            if self.artist:
                self.requester="artist:"+self.artist.name
            elif self.venue:
                self.requester="venue:"+self.venue.name
        super(Bookings,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

To create it,

```
booking1=None
try:
    # If you create booking with both artist and venue 
    # at the same time,it should throw `ValidationError`.
    booking1=Bookings.objects.create(artist=artist)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
venue = Venue.objects.create(...)
booking1.venue = venue
booking1.save()
# Get event requester from booking object.
event_requester,name  = booking1.requester.split(":")
if event_requster=="artist":
    do_something(name)
elif event_requester=="venue":
    do_something_else(name)
```